# Check if point is inside a rotated rectangle (with different rectangle origins)

Tags: rotation, point, rectangles

How can I check if a point is inside a rotaded rectangle when the rectangle can have different origins? This is basically what i'm using now:

```
struct Point 
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Rectangle
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float h;
    float origin;
    float rotation; // In degrees
};

bool contains(const Rectangle& rect, const Point& point)
{
    float c = std::cos(toRadians(-rect.rotation));
    float s = std::sin(toRadians(-rect.rotation));

    float x  = rect.x;
    float y  = rect.y;
    float w  = rect.w;
    float h  = rect.h;

    float rotX = x + c * (point.x - x) - s * (point.y - y);
    float rotY = y + s * (point.x - x) + c * (point.y - y);

    float lx = x - w / 2.f;
    float rx = x + w / 2.f;
    float ty = y - h / 2.f;
    float by = y + h / 2.f;

    return lx <= rotX && rotX <= rx && ty <= rotY && rotY <= by;
}
```

This code does work when the origin is at the center of the rectangle but not in any other origins (that i have tested). How can i make it so it also works when the origin is for example at the top-left corner of the rectangle?